# total variation of signed measures: $|\nu_1+\nu_2|\leq |\nu_1|+|\nu_2|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to solve exercise 5 of chapter 3 of Folland's:

for $\nu_1,\nu_2$ signed measures which both omit the value $+\infty$ or $-\infty$: $|\nu_1+\nu_2|\leq |\nu_1|+|\nu_2|$

eleged hint (**solution with/without the hint would be accepted**):

if $\nu=\lambda-\mu$ for $\lambda,\mu$ positive measures, then $\nu^+\leq\lambda$ and $\mu\geq\nu^-$.

What's my thought about it so far:

the hint implies $|\nu|\leq \lambda+\mu$, so it would suffice to show $\nu_1+\nu_2=|\nu_1|-|\nu_2|$. But it doesn't seem so right..
One of my problems with this question is that I don't know how to use the thing about both omitting the same value. perhaps it's only for $\nu_1+\nu_2$ to indeed be a signed measure.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\nu_1+\nu_2 = \nu_1^+ - \nu_1^- + \nu_2^+ - \nu_2^- = (\nu_1^++\nu_2^+) - (\nu_1^- + \nu_2^-), $$
so by the hint,
$$(\nu_1+\nu_2)^+ \leqslant \nu_1^+ +\nu_2^+$$
and
$$(\nu_1+\nu_2)^- \leqslant \nu_1^- + \nu_2^-.$$
It follows that
$$
\begin{align*}
|\nu_1+\nu_2| &= (\nu_1+\nu_2)^+ + (\nu_1+\nu_2)^-\\
&\leqslant (\nu_1^++\nu_2^+) + (\nu_1^-+\nu_1^-)\\
&= (\nu_1^++\nu_1^-) + (\nu_2^++\nu_2^-)\\
&= |\nu_1| + |\nu_2|.
\end{align*}
$$

The condition that $\nu_1,\nu_2$ both omit $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ is necessary to avoid expressions of the form $\infty-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

*I still don't get Folland...*

**Total Measure**

It is dominating:
$$|\mu(E)|\leq|\mu|(E)\quad(E\in\Sigma)$$
It is the smallest:
$$|\mu(E)|\leq\lambda(E)\quad(E\in\Sigma)\implies|\mu|\leq\lambda$$
*(This characterizes total measures.)*

**Problem**

By domination one has:
$$|\mu(E)+\nu(E)|\leq|\mu(E)|+|\nu(E)|\leq|\mu|(E)+|\nu|(E)$$
But it is the smallest so:
$$|\mu+\nu|\leq|\mu|+|\nu|$$

*(This holds for real and complex measures.)*

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "you don't get Folland"?   I do like your approach!